# How to set a variable in different controller in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, controllers

I'd like to do simple notifications in angular. Here is the code I've written.
http://pastebin.com/zYZtntu8
The question is: 
Why if I add a new alert in hasAlerts() method it works, but if I add a new alert in NoteController it doesn't. I've tried something with $scope.$watch but it also doesn't work or I've done something wrong.

How can I do that?

Comment: Do not fully understand the problem, what works & doesn't. Could you prepare a fiddle that will reveal the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this plnkr I made a while back

http://plnkr.co/edit/ABQsAxz1bNi34ehmPRsF?p=preview

I show a couple of ways controllers can use data from services, in particular the first two show how to do it without a watch which is generally a more efficient way to go:

```
// Code goes here

angular.module("myApp", []).service("MyService", function($q) {
  var serviceDef = {};
  //It's important that you use an object or an array here a string or other
  //primitive type can't be updated with angular.copy and changes to those
  //primitives can't be watched.
  serviceDef.someServiceData = {
    label: 'aValue'
  };
  serviceDef.doSomething = function() {
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    angular.copy({
      label: 'an updated value'
    }, serviceDef.someServiceData);

    deferred.resolve(serviceDef.someServiceData);
    return deferred.promise;
  }
  return serviceDef;
}).controller("MyCtrl", function($scope, MyService) {
  //Using a data object from the service that has it's properties updated async
  $scope.sharedData = MyService.someServiceData;
}).controller("MyCtrl2", function($scope, MyService) {
  //Same as above just has a function to modify the value as well
  $scope.sharedData = MyService.someServiceData;
  $scope.updateValue = function() {
    MyService.doSomething();
  }
}).controller("MyCtrl3", function($scope, MyService) {
  //Shows using a watch to see if the service data has changed during a digest
  //if so updates the local scope
  $scope.$watch(function(){ return MyService.someServiceData }, function(newVal){
    $scope.sharedData = newVal;
  })
  $scope.updateValue = function() {
    MyService.doSomething();
  }
}).controller("MyCtrl4", function($scope, MyService) {
  //This option relies on the promise returned from the service to update the local
  //scope, also since the properties of the object are being updated not the object
  //itself this still stays "in sync" with the other controllers and service since
  //really they are all referring to the same object.
  MyService.doSomething().then(function(newVal) {
    $scope.sharedData = newVal;
  });
});
```

The notable thing here I guess is that I use angular.copy to re-use the same object that's created in the service instead of assigning a new object or array to that property.  Since it's the same object if you reference that object from your controllers and use it in any data-binding situation (watches or {{}} interpolation in the view) will see the changes to the object.

Comment: Probably this is a solution. I just have to try to implement it to my code. Thanks.